# How to add a param to a factory-method of a factory-bean in Spring?

Tags: spring, factory

let's say I have a factory bean:

```
<bean id="myFactory" class="com.company.MyFactory" lazy-init="true">
  <property name="myProperty" ref="propA">
</bean>
```

Let's say propA is a bean injected by IOC used in the factory method. And I have 2 beans generated from this factory:

```
<bean id="bean1" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="instance"/>
<bean id="bean2" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="instance"/>
```

How can I make bean2 to use a different myProperty than bean1 without using a different factory method? Or, how can I pass propA as a parameter to the factory-method from the bean1 or bean2 configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved in a slightly different way:

```
class MyFactory {
    public Bean instance(MyProperty myProperty) {
        return //...
    }
}
```

Now you can use counterintuitive syntax like following:

```
<bean id="bean1" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="instance">
    <constructor-arg ref="propA"/>
</bean>
<bean id="bean2" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="instance">
    <constructor-arg ref="propB"/>
</bean>
```

Believe it or not but `propA` and `propB` will be used as `instance()` method arguments.